# Image in full screen from scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a `UIScrollView` and have images in that ScrollView and they are added programmatically. When I click on image, I want that image to be displayed on full screen.

What should I add to my code?
The number of images depend upon the  [images count];

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 134);
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
int X=0;

for (int i = 0; i < [images count]; i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(X, 0, 140, 136)] ;
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i]]];
    [imageView setImage: [images objectAtIndex:i]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview: imageView];
    X = X + imageView.frame.size.height+5;

    if(X > 320)
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(X, 134);
}
```

Comment: Here you have to create custom button and on click event you will have to open new xib, In which you can display fullscreen image in imageView. Give tag to a button so by which you can get data based on tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add UIImageViews then.

Instead add `UIButton` of type Custom and add the Image to the Button and add an `IBAction` to the UIButtons which adds a FullScreenView with your image.

In your `for()` for each button add a tag with i and in your IBAction function get the tag with `[sender tag]` and get your image with `[images objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]`

Example:

```
-(void)test{

for (int i = 0; i < [images count]; i++)
{

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(X, 0, 140, 136);
    [button setImage:[images objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.tag = i;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(showFullscreen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:button];
    X = X + button.frame.size.height+5;

    if(X > 320)
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(X, 134);
}

}

-(IBAction)showFullscreen:(id)sender{

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] ;
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[imageView setImage: [images objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]];
[self.view addSubview: imageView];
}
```

Comment: the image will be open in current view or new view.

Comment: then in the IBAction add something like this: UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[images objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]; [self.view addSubview:imageView];

Comment: the button is creating, but the images are not displying at button

Comment: I assumed you have UIImages in your images Array. Check if these are correct. Else you can try to set the UIImage as BackgroundImage to the UIButton: [button setBackgroundImage:[images objectAtIndex:i] forState:(UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected)];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33973/discussion-between-nasir-and-julien-klindt)